# The service on server started and stopped

Tags: sql, sql-server, service

I have been using the same SQL Server account for well over a year, and just yesterday, the process stopped working. I get different error messages, depending on where I am trying and failing to log into it.

FROM SQL Server Management Server: the system cannot find the file specified.

From services (local): windows could not start the server ... on local server.

From Registered server: the service started then stopped.

Can someone please tell me where the file that encompasses the failed database is?  If this database is truly lost to me, I hope to recapture the stored procedures, functions, table types, etc. that the database defines, even if I can't install it again.

From the services, I am able to enable the Full-text filter daemon Launcher, but nothing else.

- SQL Server: Windows could not start the SQL Server ... on local computer.
- SQL Server Agent: the dependence group or service failed to start.
- Analysis services: the process terminated unexpectedly

In every case, the desired server shows up, but these are the roadblocks thrown my way by the various means at my disposal to find out more.  Your suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you found your instance's ERRORLOG file and inspected it in Notepad/your-favorite-text-editor to see what error messages are there? There could be any number of reasons that SQL Server is failing to start ranging from missing files, broken file system ACLs, another active process owning the TCP/IP sockets it needs, lack of memory and anti-virus interference.

Answer (score 0):

Please looked into the properties of the service, check whether the file path of SQL server service executable file is correct. It is better to share us more related information from error log or windows event log.